# computeDistanceBetween Java vs Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I am using google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween in Javascript and computeDistanceBetween from SphericalUtil in Java.

https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.java

I am getting different distances for the same positions. Is there anything I can do to calibrate them to be the same or are there two libraries I can use that can get me similar results in the front end (Javascript) and back end (Java)?

Below are some values and an example:

In Javascript:

```
var from = new google.maps.LatLng(33.44138, -111.97500000000002);
var to = new google.maps.LatLng(33.505904166596224, -112.09470748901367);
var distanceBetween = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(from, to);
console.log(distanceBetween);
```

In Java:

```
LatLng from = new LatLng(Float.parseFloat("33.44138"), Float.parseFloat("-111.97500000000002"));
LatLng to = new LatLng(Float.parseFloat("33.505904166596224"), Float.parseFloat("-112.09470748901367"));
double distanceBetween = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(from, to);
System.out.println(distanceBetween);
```

In Java with Double instead of Float:

```
LatLng from = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble("33.44138"), Double.parseDouble("-111.97500000000002"));
LatLng to = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble("33.505904166596224"), Double.parseDouble("-112.09470748901367"));
double distanceBetween = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(from, to);
System.out.println(distanceBetween);
```

The Javascript value is: 13234.355969270651
The Java (float) value is: 13219.474110913057
The Java (double) value is: 13219.565680296535

Thanks!

Comment: Different float pointing precision types?

Comment: Hey, you are Amir, not Robert! Please, post your code and results to compare.

Comment: Okay, I will add examples.

Comment: Okay, I added an example. You can see there is a difference between the outputs now. Thanks!

Comment: Its likely a difference in the underlying model of the earth.  Google likely uses a oblate spheroid while the Java model appears to use a spherical model - but I can't confirm this.    You can check out a bunch of models at http://edwilliams.org/gccalc.htm.

Comment: Can you try precision by checking result of `Float.parseFloat("9999999999999999")`?

Comment: @MichaelMcKay Do you know of any good libraries I could use that are available in both JS and Java? Or is your suggestion to write my own?

Comment: @RobertGarcia, Unfortunately, no - not that I'm aware of, but I'm sure they exist.  Some of the libraries are open source so you could always convert the math yourself.

Comment: I can't believe google uses different models for Java and JavaScript languages.

Answer (score 2):

Check the documentation for the value of earth radius that is used.

Try using this code to compare results to the 2 others.

```
Tier3Toolbox.EARTH_RADIUS = 6378137; /* Equitorial Radius instead of 6371000 */
Tier3Toolbox.toRad = 
    function (num) {
        return num * Math.PI / 180;
    };  
Tier3Toolbox.calculateDistance =
    function(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2){
        var dLat = this.toRad(lat2 - lat1);
        var dLon = this.toRad(lon2 - lon1);
        var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + Math.cos(this.toRad(lat1)) * 
                Math.cos(this.toRad(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
        var distance = this.EARTH_RADIUS * 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        return distance;
    }
```

Comment: Same code but using 6378137 for the radius instead of 6371000 got me much closer. The Java result is now 13234.264297438078. So it looks like the google maps javascript code uses the equatorial radius behind the scenes. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has [52 significant bits](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp) in a floating point number, it is ~15 significant digits of a floating point number. Java's float has only 24 bits of precision. Remember, that distance formulae contains subtraction. If you subtract two non-precised values, that are close enough, you can obtain a huge error.

Try to change `Float` into `Double`: `Double.parseDouble()`.

Comment: So I tried Double on the Java side at your suggestion. The value is slightly different from the Float Java value but still roughly 5 meters different (put example and value in original post).

Comment: It's an amazing question.

Comment: It's really frustrating! :P